# Fix loop with which to mimic index&match in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to mimic EXCEL formula with INDEX and MATCH in R with WHICH in loop, but the results are NA.

The formula in EXCEL with INDEX and MATCH put data in order I need, but the it doesn't work well in R. This is a sample of EXCEL like data:

- nr    TRUNK   lemat   HEAD
- 1 balony  balon   2
- 2 są  być 4
- 3 swobodne    swobodny    2
- 4 ale ale 14
- 5 w   w   4
- 6 ramach  rama    5
- 7 długości    długość 6
- 8 sznurka sznurek 7
- 9 [   [   14
- 10    #   #   9

I can join words from column TRUNK based on numbers from column HEAD.

- HEAD  TRUNK   JOINT
- są    balony  są balony
- ale   są  ale są
- są    swobodne    są swobodne
- to    ale to ale
- ale   w   ale w
- w ramach  w ramach
- ramach    długości    ramach długości
- długości  sznurka długości sznurka
- to    [   to [

The formula for column HEAD takes data to INDEX from TRUNK and MATCH the word [balony] with a word from HEAD based on its number [2], that is [są]. In other words, the formula generates two-word-phrases from table. 
=INDEX(PARSER!B:B;(MATCH(PARSER!G3;PARSER!A:A;0)))

Now in R I can read the data, make data.frames and for loop to fill new table with head and trunk words, but it doesn't work well.

```
graf <- read.csv("graf.txt", sep = "\t", quote = "\t", header = FALSE)
names(graf)[1] = "nr"
names(graf)[2] = "trunk"
names(graf)[3] = "lemat"
names(graf)[4] = "head"
nrheaddf = cbind.data.frame(graf$head,as.character(graf$trunk))
names(nrheaddf)[1] = "HEAD"
names(nrheaddf)[2] = "TRUNK"
nrtrunkdf = cbind.data.frame(graf$nr,as.character(graf$trunk))
names(nrtrunkdf)[1] = "NR"
names(nrtrunkdf)[2] = "TRUNK"



as.character(nrheaddf$TRUNK[6]) #BALONY
which(nrtrunkdf$NR == as.character(nrheaddf$HEAD[6])) #7
nrtrunkdf$TRUNK[which(nrtrunkdf$NR == as.character(nrheaddf$HEAD[6]))[1]] #są
grafi <- as.numeric(count(graf))
JOINER <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = grafi, ncol = 2))
joinv <- list()
for (i in grafi) {
  joinv <- nrtrunkdf$V2[which(nrheaddf$V1 == nrtrunkdf$V1[i])][1]
  JOINER[i] <- joinv
}
```

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = NULL) : 
  new columns would leave holes after existing columns

#### NEW DATA:

```
head(WSD$Lemma)
```

"ktoś"     "go"       "krokodyl" "myśleć"   "barwić"
"szkło"

```
head(KEYWORDS$V1)
```

"ktoś go"               "krokodyl się"
"ja myślę"              "barwione szkło"
"mi się"                "nieokreślone kształty"

```
WSDKEY <- as.data.frame(cbind.na(WSD$Lemma,KEYWORDS$V1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

But then this solution does not work:
    get_head <- function(i){
        if (!(i %in% WSDKEY$V2))
            return(NA)
        else
            head <- WSDKEY[WSDKEY$V2 == i,'V1']
        return(as.character(head))
    }

Comment: To be honest , I don't really get what you're trying to do. Can you explain the logic with which you are joining these words? or better yet, assuming the above is a sample input data, what does the expected output look like?

Comment: The output is not the same as the input, some words come out in different pairs. The input table is a result of INDEPENDENCY PARSER from CLARIN website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean:

```
library(dplyr)
# The used Data
my_data <- read.table(text = "nr TRUNK lemat HEAD
                1 balony balon 2
                2 są być 4
                3 swobodne swobodny 2
                4 ale ale 14
                5 w w 4
                6 ramach rama 5
                7 długości długość 6
                8 sznurka sznurek 7
                9 [ [ 14
                10 '#' '#' 9", header = TRUE)
my_data

my_data %>% 
  mutate(HEAD = my_data[HEAD, 'TRUNK']) %>%                # replace the numbers with the values from TRUNK
  mutate(joined_text = paste(HEAD, TRUNK)) %>%        # paste the text together in a new column
  select(HEAD, TRUNK, joined_text)                    # select the needed columns
```

then I get this:

```
#       HEAD    TRUNK      joined_text
#         są   balony        są balony
#        ale       są           ale są
#         są swobodne      są swobodne
#       <NA>      ale           NA ale
#        ale        w            ale w
#          w   ramach         w ramach
#     ramach długości  ramach długości
#   długości  sznurka długości sznurka
#       <NA>        [             NA [
#         [        #              [ #
```

**Update:**

Here's another way which also works if you don't want to rely on row indices

```
# define a function to find and extract the right HEAD
get_head <- function(i){
  if (!(i %in% my_data$nr))
    return(NA)
  else
    head <- my_data[my_data$nr == i,'TRUNK']
    return(as.character(head))
}

# replace with the new values
my_data$HEAD <- sapply(my_data$HEAD, get_head)

# now concatenate the text and select the columns you want
my_data %>% 
  mutate(joined_text = paste(HEAD, TRUNK)) %>%        # paste the text together in a new column
  select(HEAD, TRUNK, joined_text)
```

This method also works if you want to match strings instead of numbers.

Comment: I believe it works, however:

    mutate(my_data, HEAD = df[HEAD, 'TRUNK'])
    Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable.

Comment: Sorry! my mistake, this should be `my_data` instead of `df`. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works on the sample.

Now, after I've loaded new data, longer table, I've got another error

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `HEAD` must be length 83 (the number of rows) or one, not 0

Comment: My method is using the index instead of the `nr` column, could this be the cause of the problem? I mean is it possible - for example -  that the `HEAD` column has the number 0 in some row?

Comment: No, the Head can’t have 0 number since it can only have numbers of words given to trunk. It’s just a different order and some words and their numbers maybe assigned to more then one Word. Thanks for HELP.

Comment: Are the values of the column `nr` unique? Meaning, can two different rows have the same `nr` value?

Comment: I’d rather like same functionality as in excel, because I have used index and match formuła with data that are not numeric at all. I’ll upload more samples soon. I’d likw to be able to find those chunks of words that contain certain words